# Javascript: I hear my alert but it's not showing in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, alert

I've got a very basic HTML page, which only has to show a javascript alert.

I hear the sound that it's supposed to make when it pops up, but it's not popping up! I don't see it anywhere (in google chrome it does pop up). I also can continue working on my page without clicking "ok" on the (invisible) alert box, so that means that it really isn't there!

Any clues on how to solve this? I already rebooted my pc and disconnect my multiple monitors.

```
<script>
    alert('SHOW!!');
</script>
```

More info:

- My IE version is IE11
- The popup did work properly before, without making changes to IE
- On other websites, the popup isn't showing aswell
- I did reset my IE properties (to factory default), no result
- unable to test on older versions
- Javascript is enabled

Comment: Maybe you checked the box that says not to show any more alerts from that page?

Comment: Pls, provide more information. Browser cache, IE version, does your IE shows alerts on other web pages, have you enabling or disabling javascript in IE and this alert and, have you try to re-setup IE, what about other versions of IE and so on. At current stage question can be closed for low quality

Comment: What do you mean with browser cache, if that is enabled? How would that help you solve this problem? (it is enabled though).

Comment: are you use some popup blockers, or browser plugins, or something like this?

Comment: nope nothing.. the only thing I can think of now is that Microsoft forced me an upgrade which caused the problem.

Comment: Ok... strange... did not change anything (really, I didn't) and it's working again.